# Fail2ban continuous log flood, what's happening?

Tags: ssh, log, fail2ban

A couple of days ago I noticed my server got very sluggish. When I investigated I noticed `fail2ban` was going crazy, the `fail2ban-server` process taking up 50% of CPU, and the `fail2ban` log file is getting flooded with exclusive `sshd` ban messages (about 3 lines/IPs per second)

I've shut down my server for a couple of days, and when I booted it up again this morning, `fail2ban` continued to flood the log file.

From what I understand, fail2ban scans the appropriate log files for suspicious behaviour. And (failed) ssh attempts are logged in auth.log.

I can not match what I see in the `fail2ban` log with the entries in the `auth.log`. There is hardly anything logged in auth.log, mostly CRON messages once every few minutes.

I'm not a Linux guru myself, so I may be overlooking something, but I can't explain what is happening here. Why is the `fail2ban` log getting flooded with these messages while everything else seems at peace?

```
$ tail fail2ban.log
2020-03-14 12:41:29,262 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.114.186.199
2020-03-14 12:41:29,692 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.114.187.117
2020-03-14 12:41:30,122 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.114.191.123
2020-03-14 12:41:30,555 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.117.180.69
2020-03-14 12:41:30,990 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.120.12.212
2020-03-14 12:41:31,426 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.120.33.30
2020-03-14 12:41:31,864 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.128.219.17
2020-03-14 12:41:32,297 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.130.120.244
2020-03-14 12:41:32,729 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.130.156.39
2020-03-14 12:41:33,164 fail2ban.actions        [1557]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 37.135.117.97
```

```
fail2ban-server v0.9.3,
ubuntu 16.04.6
```

Comment: In recent years ssh attackers have become more clever, merely switching to another ip address once they get blocked. Try just blocking 37.0.0.0/8 permanently. Use tcpdump, or wireshark, to observe the packets themselves.

Comment: You can look in /etc/fail2ban/paths-common.conf to see what file the sshd filter is using, but normally as you say it is auth.log

Comment: @DougSmythies the output was just an example of what was going on at that moment. Many IPs  were logged, no particular range. Luckily the flood ended shortly by itself. Still not sure what caused it, I'll investigate further.